# How to unit test logic from a static initialization block?

Tags: java, spring

I have a private static final List in one of my classes, that I initialize via a static initialization block.

```
private static final List<String> list;

static {
    list = //lambda expression
}
```

How do I go on writing tests for something such as this? This is a list of Strings that will NEVER change.

Comment: You might consider switching that to `private static final List<String> list = //lambda expression`. If not, you should probably make it a static initialization block with `static { list = /*lambda expression*/ }` since the variable is also static.

Comment: Agreed.  1) The code in your example won't compile.  2) That's not a `static` initialization block.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to test here? The contents of the list are exactly as expected? If so, first make your variable visible for testing. (Another alternative is to use reflections to get the contents of the list, but this approach is way more simple). Also, you have an error in the code that you posted. You are trying to initialize a static variable in a non-static block. I would advice you to switch to **static** block as the list gets initialized once, when the class itself is initialized, no matter how many objects of that type you create.

```
enum Example {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

@VisibleForTesting static final List<String> list;
static {
    list = Arrays.asList(Example.values()).stream()
            .map(Example::name)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can ignore the `@VisibleForTesting` annotation. It's just a nice to have and indicates that you changed the scope to package-private in order to test the variable. I recommend using AssertJ as it has some cool testing methods. For example you can assert the contents of your list in your test like this:

```
assertThat(Foo.list).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("B", "A", "C");
```

If you want to assert the contents in order you can use the `containsExactly("A", "B", "C")` method. If your list is dynamically generated and you don't know the contents, you can just assert that the size is as expected using the `hasSize(3)` method.

Comment: In the static initialization block I am initializing a private static final List with the values of an Enum, as Strings.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Static state is problematic from a unit testing perspective.  This is one of the reasons that Dependency Injection is used ... by Spring!

The best that you can do is to write a unit test that checks that the statics *have been* initialized to an expected state.

You say:

> This is a list of Strings that will NEVER change.

It depends on what you mean  by NEVER:

- You can (almost) never guarantee that something will NEVER change.  You may need to change your code to cater for new requirements.
- If you can enumerate the expected values and hard-wire them into the code of your unit test, you are OK.  Of course, if your code changes, you may need to change the unit test.  But that's OK too.
- If the values your are testing may depend on the environment, or on the results of some previous initialization, then you have a **big problem**.  As per the JLS, the class initialization can only be performed once in the lifetime of a JVM.

  If you are in this situation, the "solutions" are:

  - Get rid of the static entirely; e.g. replace it with DI.
  - Restructure it to be testable; e.g. do it using static method that can be tested.
  - Run the entire test suite multiple times *in different JVMs*, once for each of the different initialization paths.
  - Don't test the initialization in the unit tests.